# Why does adding new elements to a div push the entire div upwards?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This is a very strange problem and I am not sure where to begin. I tried changing my divs from relative positioning to absolute but that seemed to have no impact on the problem.

When there is a certain number of elements in my `#all_galleries` div it is aligned properly:

[image]

But if I add too many elements the div is pushed upwards:

[image]

Why is this div being pushed upwards when elements are added to it?

**main.css**

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  height: 700px;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: #2F96E8;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#search_query {
  height: 18px;
  width: 200px;
}

#new_search {
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#signout {
  position: absolute;
  right: 76px;
  top: 10px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}

#create_gallery {
  background-color: rgb(96, 201, 231);
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 250%;
}

#create_group {
  background-color: rgb(141, 197, 62);
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 250%;
}

#galleries_tagline {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 170px;
  right: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#groups_tagline {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 220px;
  left: 130px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.gallery_image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
}

#groups {
  text-align: left;
}

#groups li {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

#all_groups {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 131px;
}

#all_galleries {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  left: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#login {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**app/views/galleries/index.html.erb**

```
<h2>Choose Your Creation</h2>
<%= link_to '<button type="button" id="create_gallery">Galleries</button>'.html_safe, new_gallery_path %>
<%= link_to '<button type="button" id="create_group">Groups</button>'.html_safe, new_group_path %>
<p class="tagline" id="galleries_tagline">Show some pix</p>
<p class="tagline" id="groups_tagline">Share with friends</p>

<div id="all_galleries">
<h3>Current Galleries</h3>
  <% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
    <p><%= link_to gallery.name, gallery %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="all_groups">
  <h3>Current Groups</h3>
  <% @groups.each do |group| %>
    <p><%= link_to group.name, group %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating the issue from the code you posted. Can you create a fiddle or post a link?

Comment: https://amzotti-pixtr.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, there is a username and password required though

Comment: Just click signup and create an account. No email validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the simple answer is because you're using `position: absolute` and its relative parent is `main` so as the container grows larger, your `bottom` values don't stay consistent. The bigger problem is your entire code structure is quite frankly a mess. It really needs to be restructured which I have done. The only difference is I removed the use of the `button` tags and used `div`s instead.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgw7f9bb/)

**HTML**

```
<main>
   <h2>Choose Your Creation</h2>

   <div class="button-wrapper">           
     <a href="/galleries/new" class="button-container">
       <div id="create_gallery" class="button gallery">
          <div class="text-wrapper">
             Galleries   
             <p class="tagline" id="galleries_tagline">Show some pix</p>
          </div>
       </div>
     </a>

     <div id="all_galleries">
        <h3>Current Galleries</h3>
        <p><a href="/galleries/1">Barbecue listing</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/2">Outback Crocz!</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/3">leet pix</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/4">Mountains</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/6">Star-Trek-Memes</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/1">Barbecue listing</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/2">Outback Crocz!</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/3">leet pix</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/4">Mountains</a></p>
        <p><a href="/galleries/6">Star-Trek-Memes</a></p>
     </div>

   </div> 

   <div class="button-wrapper">     
      <a href="/groups/new" class="button-container">
         <div id="create_group" class="button group">
            <div class="text-wrapper">
              Groups
              <p class="tagline" id="groups_tagline">Share with friends</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>

      <div id="all_groups">
        <h3>Current Groups</h3>
        <p><a href="/groups/1">Hip photographers anon</a></p>
        <p><a href="/groups/2">Camper Clan</a></p>
        <p><a href="/groups/3">Crocodiles Anonymous</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>     

</main>
```

**Added CSS**

```
.button-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.button-wrapper a.button-container{
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button{
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 250%;
  border-top: 2px solid #cccece;
  border-left: 2px solid #cccece;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #68797e;
  border-right: 2px solid #68797e; 
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button.gallery{
  background-color: #60c9e7;
}

.button.groups{
  background-color: #60c9e7;
}

.text-wrapper{
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pushed upwards because the `#all_galleries` div is absolutely positioned to the bottom.

You might be better off using floated divs for each column, and let the content flow naturally. You should only use absolute positioning in special cases when nothing else does the job.